# Connect R to Quickbooks

Tags: r, quickbooks

Has anyone connected the R package to QuickBooks?  I know there is an ODBC driver than can be bought.  Just wondering if anyone has already gone down this road.

Any insight will be much appreciated!

~ Brock

Comment: And what about for just regular quicken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google QODBC. It allows you to access Quickbooks via ODBC.

However, it works through creating an interface to XML files. For large QB files it can be painfully slow if you don't properly use indices and limit the data to exactly what is necessary. It's also very quirky. Lastly, not all tables are exposed (Quickbooks fault, not theirs) such as some payroll tables.

What I often ended up doing for large QB files is exporting the data at night via the QODBC driver into a sql database so that ad hoc analysis could be run quickly without compromising the performance for QB users during the day.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I knew QODBC was out there, but wondering about performance.  I definitely will throw it into a database before hitting it with R.  Much appreciated.